# Date Range doesn't get clones

Tags: javascript

To get the dates picked in `input` I'm using [data range picker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/)
The issue I'm having is that when a `input` gets cloned the date function doesn't work anymore and I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.
It seems that I can only once execute the data picker function.

```js
$(function() {

  $('input[name="opl_datum"]').daterangepicker({
      autoUpdateInput: false,
      showDropdowns: true,
      autoApply: true,
      locale: {
          format:'DD/MM/YYYY',
          daysOfWeek: [
           'Zo',
           'Ma',
           'Di',
           'Wo',
           'Do',
           'Vr',
           'Za',
          ]
      }
  });

  $('input[name="opl_datum"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
      $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
   });
   
     $(document).on('click', '.btn-add', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var controlForm = $(this).closest('.controls').find('form:first'),//you have to select colsest controls
      currentEntry = $(this).parents('.entry:first'),
      newEntry = $(currentEntry.clone()).appendTo(controlForm);

    newEntry.find('input').val('');
    controlForm.find('.entry:not(:last) .btn-add')
      .removeClass('btn-add').addClass('btn-remove')
      .removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')
      .html('<span class="icon_minus_alt2"></span>');
  }).on('click', '.btn-remove', function(e) {
    $(this).parents('.entry:first').remove();

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  });
  

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
<div class="controls">
  <form class="school_form" role="form" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="entry input-group">
      <input type="text" name="opl_datum" placeholder="Periode">
      <input type="text" name="diploma" placeholder="Certicicaat/diploma">
      <input type="text" name="school" placeholder="School/Hoge School/ Universiteit">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-success btn-add" type="button">
          <span>Voeg opleinding toe</span>
      </button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, jQuery's [clone](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) method will not clone the event handlers and the data associated to the DOM node, only the node itself. You must pass a specific parameters ([*withDataAndEvents* and *deepWithDataEvents*](https://api.jquery.com/clone/#clone-withDataAndEvents-deepWithDataAndEvents)) to `clone` in order to get those copied as well.